# make APK with specific information

Tags: android, apk, project

my question about publish project to my customers but should be each customer get specific APK with own information inside the APP.
My APP not necessary connect to internet then will be predefined for each customer.
this mean Main Activity appears with information and image of each customer and rest of APP working same as all customer.
please help to found solution.

Comment: Where will be your customer specific data, I mean your main activity screen data, is this from SQLite database or server???

Comment: I will be add for each customer one by one inside activity main XML, as per my idea, but I am not sure is this correct or no>

Comment: If your data is static then you just design the activity_main.xml with your customer specific data hard coded in the XML file itself and place it in the layout and get the .apk. Do it for all the customers individually. If your data is static (Not getting from the remote server, then this is the solution you can go for)

Comment: yes, my data for each customer is static and specific. problem when happen I want publish new version, then should be make project for each customer. that is problem if customer more or more.

Comment: If you have more then one customer for one set of framework you are building, then you should have separate apk for each individual customer with different package name for each customer. If there is any data change for specific customer then you should change the data in the code level and release that customer specific .apk. Until you stick to the static data this is the only one solution even it's little more hard for you to build!!!

Comment: If you need smart solution better go with remote server and maintain each customer specific data over there, have a server to access the data.

Comment: thanks a lot dear @Bethan

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to connect the application to the internet and still want to verify, you can always use mobile numbers.
But anything hardcoded at the client side is not safe, as the information for those users can be leaked.

Comment: if I want to verify for one time, then what is you opinion?

Comment: What you can do here is: Create a backend code to verify only the "predefined users", while connected to Internet, and if the user is not connected to Internet then they can use the application as normal users. So it will satisfy what you want and it will be secure